# What is wrong with my pepper plants?

Tags: peppers, bell-peppers

We started a small garden this year. We are growing both bell peppers and jalapeño peppers. Both of them have the same issue where the top leaves are shriveling, but there is no yellowing or other issues. Is this a case of overwatering? Is it a soil PH issue? Any clues would be helpful!

[image: Jalepeno]
[image: Bell Peppers]

Comment: Get a magnifying glass and look for insects or fungus.  Any unusual weather? Hot, cold, wet, dry. Any unusual chemicals nearby? Herbicide, road salt, paint.

Answer (score 2):

Step closer and start looking for any type of insects. Usually worms/caterpillars form under the leave and use most of the leave to cover themselves by eating it or morphing to the next stage. Depending on the type of bug it can become a infestation pretty fast and eat your leaves.

A disease cause also cause this twirling but, for me it looks like more of a bug problem to me.

If it was an issue with not enough sun then it would have different symptoms such as less color on the leave or more browning.

Can also be an issue with certain lack of vitamins.

https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/pepper/curling-leaves-on-peppers.htm

https://peppergeek.com/pepper-plant-leaves-curling/